# Classification implementation and visualization in scatter using python

Tags: python, classification, scatter-plot, multiclass-classification

so I have these dataset which
from September till December
week 1 till week 6...
Monday till Sunday

I want to display the dataset by scatter plot. Where the x axis= Monday - Sunday, y axis=week1-week6 and the content of the plot is SUMBEI_CLEANED that have been classify to label1-label6...
is it possible? if possible how?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn98G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html). It is a powerful Python visualization library built on top of the well known matplotlib library, and works very well with pandas. Since scatter plot is a very common data visualization, it is implemented in [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html). Seaborn can handle well multidimensional data too.